# Who exactly is controlling Stefan?

Tags: black-mirror, bandersnatch

Is it PAC (Program and Control) or Netflix user? I rewatched *Black Mirror Bandersnatch:* (2018) movie, but confused due to multiple realities.

Comment: PAC is you. -> press c to accept